# listView, add 2 dataRows from firebase in one row

Tags: react-native

how can i render 2 items in a list view? 
i am using firebase to get my data, and i want to put 2 data in one row

i am using this code to add 1 item

```
   constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
        swipeToClose: true,
  dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
  })
};
this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('movies');
}

   render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
      style={styles.listview}
  </View>
);
 }


 _renderItem(item) {
const onPress = () => {
  AlertIOS.prompt(
    'Complete',
    null,
    [
      {text: 'Complete', onPress: (text) => this.itemsRef.child(item._key).remove()},
      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: (text) => console.log('Cancelled')}
    ],
    'default'
    );
     };

    return (
    <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
 <TouchableHighlight style={styles.leftContainer}  onPress={onPress}> 
  <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
    <Image
     defaultSource={require('./noimage.png')}
      source={{uri: item.image}}
      style={styles.thumbnail}/>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.year}>{item.year}</Text>
  </View>
   </TouchableHighlight>
 </View>
);

   }

  }
```

should i change this.state.dataSource or something else

Comment: When you say you want to put two data in one row, do you mean two buttons?

Comment: i mean that i want to read 2 rows of data from fireBase and show them in one row of the list view

Comment: each row of data contains: (year,title and image)

Comment: do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your ListView to be like :

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.listView}
        />
      </View>
       );
     }
```

then let your styles class be like :

```
import React, {
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width; //full screen width
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...
    },
    listView: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',//here you are telling the list view to wrap its items next to each others
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    rowContainer: {
         width:width/2, //here you make row item half width according to screen width
    }
});
```